# Redux toolkit and React native TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, asyncstorage

I am new to redux , redux toolkit and I got an error message that I really struggle to deal with but i need some help. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

My error :

> ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> 'state.favorites.favorites')

my code :

reducer.ts

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { IFavorite, MEATPROPS, IFavoriteState } from "../../../types/meat";
const initialState = {
  favorites: [],
};

const FavoriteData = createSlice({
  name: "favoriteData",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addNewFavoriteCharacter: (
      state: IFavorite,
      action: PayloadAction<MEATPROPS>
    ) => {
      state.favorites = [...state.favorites, action.payload];
    },
    removeFavoriteCharacter: (
      state: IFavorite,
      action: PayloadAction<number>
    ) => {
      state.favorites = state.favorites.filter(
        (item) => item.id !== action.payload
      );
    },
  },
});

export const { addNewFavoriteCharacter, removeFavoriteCharacter } =
  FavoriteData.actions;

export const favoriteStateData = (state: IFavoriteState) =>
  state.favorites.favorites;
  

export default FavoriteData.reducer;
```

app.tsx

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { AppNavigation } from "./src/appNavigation";
import { useFonts, Poppins_500Medium } from "@expo-google-fonts/poppins";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react';
import { persistor, store } from "./src/store";
export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Sangharia: require("./src/fonts/Sangharia.ttf"),
    Poppins_500Medium: Poppins_500Medium,
  });
  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}></PersistGate>

      <SafeAreaProvider onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
        <AppNavigation />
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

types.ts

```
export interface MEATPROPS {
  id: number;
  meatType: "Beef" | "Pork" | "Sheep" | "Chicken";
  image?: any;
  name: string;
  simplifiedDescription?: string;
  fullDescription?: string;
  countriesNaming?: countries;
  bestTo: string[];
  popularity?: "baixa" | "tradicional" | "alta";
  nutriFact?: Nutrition;
}
export interface IFavorite{
  favorites: MEATPROPS[]
}
export interface IFavoriteState{
  favorites:{
    favorites: MEATPROPS[]
  }

}
```

store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

import favoriteData from "./modules/Favorites/reducer";
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, favoriteData);
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    favoriteData: persistedReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

I'm trying to persist data on local storage

Comment: Let's see your store setup.

Comment: I just added above

Comment: see here full code with redux may be this will help you https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-cloud-jhlqqr?file=/src/App.js:0-2307

Answer (score 1):

Your slice name is "favoriteData". When you call favorites from the state you should use `state.favoriteData.favorites` not `state.favorites.favorites`

Fix this code:

```
export const favoriteStateData = (state: IFavoriteState) =>
  state.favoriteData.favorites  // use this here
```

I hope it helps